# How to access Session in .ashx file?

Tags: c#

I want to access some value(which is already set in.aspx file) in .ashx file. I tried to get that value using querystring, session etc but each time it failed. Can anyone suggest me how can we access session value in .ashx file?

Comment: "HttpContext.Current.Session" i have try this butt always get exception.

Comment: What exception you are getting?

Comment: @mrd it is showing NullReference Exception in .ashx file. I followed this post but still getting exception.

Comment: it works fine for me...can you also try using this....System.Web.SessionState.IReadOnlySessionState or System.Web.SessionState.IRequiresSessionState....??

Comment: @KashifR I already included this. Actually it is showing null in the variable.I dont know why. In .aspx file value stored in variable but while getting it in .ashx file it is not showing.

Comment: can you post your code here....so that i can check..please also make header like this

public class FileUpload : IHttpHandler,System.Web.SessionState.IRequiresSessionState

Then get in session like this

spaceused = context.Session["SpaceUsed"] + "";

Answer (score 60, accepted):

**In aspx file:**

```
Session.Add("filename", "Test.txt");
```

After you have set session value in aspx file. Use following to get the value in ashx file.

**In ashx file:**

```
public class ImageHandler : IHttpHandler, System.Web.SessionState.IRequiresSessionState
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
      string Name = "";
      if (context.Session["filename"] != null)
         Name = context.Session["filename"].ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: How to set a session variable?
context.Session["filename"] = "somevalue"; 

is it right?

Comment: If you are setting session variable in aspx page then just use Session("filename") = "somevalue". And if you are setting in handler as above then use context.Session["filename"] = "somevalue".

Comment: They key part of this answer is that the handler must be modified to inherit from IRequiresSessionState in order to have access to the Session.

Answer (score 80):

In the ashx.cs file, also "implement" the interface [`System.Web.SessionState.IReadOnlySessionState`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.sessionstate.ireadonlysessionstate) or [`System.Web.SessionState.IRequiresSessionState`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.sessionstate.irequiressessionstate).

You don't have to implement any method, just the presence of this makes the Session available (in readonly or read/write mode), through `context.Session`.

The header would look like:

```
public class MyHandler: IHttpHandler, System.Web.SessionState.IReadOnlySessionState
```

Comment: I love you.  For some reason this issue was only manifesting for me in Visual Studio 2013 (VS2013).  Could be because of the .NET version or IIS Express Version it uses (IIS 7?)  Thanks for the help!

Comment: While this answer is helpful, the accepted answer also includes this in the first line of the example code:

    public class ImageHandler : IHttpHandler, System.Web.SessionState.IRequiresSessionState

Answer (score -3):

Try this,

```
HttpContext.Current.Session
```

Comment: this still requires the information from the above answer